# Exporting a function whose name starts with a lower case letter

Tags: go

Just curious, is there a way to export a function whose name starts with a lower case character, like "print" or "start"?

A side note: just like you do with JSON:

```
type T struct {
    FieldA int    `json:"field_a"`
    FieldB string `json:"field_b,omitempty"`
}
```

Comment: Your JSON example doesn't export fields that start with lowercase letters. The exported fields are called `FieldA` and `FieldB` respective--clearly beginning with uppercase letters.

Comment: @Flimzy the output JSON will have the lowercase-started identifiers, that's what I need for my library as well. Isn't that obvious, why downvote for such an artificial complain?

Comment: The output JSON has nothing to do with exported variables, except that the json Marshaler, for obvious reasons, can _only access exported variables_. So if anything, it's the exact opposite of what you claim.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is not. The [Go language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) specifies this clearly:

> #### Exported identifiers
>
> An identifier may be exported to permit access to it from another package. An identifier is exported if both:
>
> 1. the first character of the identifier's name is a Unicode upper case letter (Unicode class "Lu"); and
> 2. the identifier is declared in the package block or it is a field name or method name.
>
> All other identifiers are not exported.